# Resolving a three-way circular reference in SQL (Django)

Tags: python, sql, django, database-design

Currently I have three models in Django that create a circular reference:

A `User` can live in a `Location`.
A `Location` must be part of a `Property`.
A `Property` must have an owner, which is a `User`.

The reason I want each `User` to specify a location is for people living in apartments. An apartment tenant would live in a numbered room, but a house tenant wouldn't. But notice that location can also simply be just a property (ie a house tenant lives in a location which is just the property with an address; the property doesn't have room numbers, floors, or buildings.).

Here is the (stripped down) code:

```
class User( models.Model ) :
    TYPE_CHOICES = (
        ( 't', 'tenant'           ),
        ( 'o', 'property owner'   ),
        ( 'v', 'vendor'           ),
        ( 'm', 'property manager' ),
    )

    user_type  = models.CharField( max_length = 1, choices = TYPE_CHOICES, default = 't' )
    first_name = models.CharField( max_length = 135 )
    last_name  = models.CharField( max_length = 135 )
    location   = models.ForeignKey( Location, null = True, blank = True )

class Property( models.Model ) :
    name             = models.CharField( max_length = 135 )
    owner            = models.ForeignKey( User )
    address_line_one = models.CharField( max_length = 135 )
    address_line_two = models.CharField( max_length = 135, blank = True )
    city             = models.CharField( max_length = 135 )
    state            = models.CharField( max_length = 135 )
    zip_code         = models.CharField( max_length = 135 )

class Location( models.Model ) :
    room       = models.CharField( max_length = 135, blank = True )
    floor      = models.CharField( max_length = 135, blank = True )
    building   = models.CharField( max_length = 135, blank = True )
    prop       = models.ForeignKey( Property )
```

Please let me know if you guys need more clarification or code. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Perhaps just change it so that `Location`s have an `occupant`, rather than `Users` having a `location`?

Comment: @Amber Ah ok, so a `Location` can have a many-to-many relationship with an occupant (`User`)?

Comment: Actually a `User` can only live in one `Location` at a time, so is it possible to have a one-to-many??? That doesn't make sense to me, if it's many-to-one, then we're back at the circular reference again...

Comment: See my answer for 1-to-many. You could have many-to-many, too, without circular paths. (just remove the Unique constaint)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#module-django.db.models.fields.related) say, you can use a string to specify the app and model to use in a relation.

> If you need to create a relationship on a model that has not yet been defined, you can use the name of the model, rather than the model object itself

Comment: Thanks for the link. Is it normally a good practice to have circular foreign key references like this? I understand for these kinds of references, once of the reference needs to be optional (can be NULL). If it's not good practice, then for my case, any suggestions on how I should resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Circular paths in tables' references can get you into serious problems that can be solved with tricky and cumbersome solutions (and not all such solutions work in all DBMS).

If you want to avoid them, you should redesign the tables. Possible way is to remove the `User -> Location` Foreign Key (it's the only one that is not mandatory, in your words: *"A User **can** live in a Location"*, the other use *"must"*) and make a separate table for that (optional) relationship.

```
class User( models.Model ) :
    TYPE_CHOICES = (
        ( 't', 'tenant'           ),
        ( 'o', 'property owner'   ),
        ( 'v', 'vendor'           ),
        ( 'm', 'property manager' ),
    )

    user_type  = models.CharField( max_length = 1
                                 , choices = TYPE_CHOICES, default = 't' )
    first_name = models.CharField( max_length = 135 )
    last_name  = models.CharField( max_length = 135 )

class UserLocation( models.Model ) :
    person          = models.ForeignKey( User )
    person.unique   = True 
    apartm_location = models.ForeignKey( Location )
```